# isinstance of bool?

Tags: python, boolean, isinstance

in Python, i'd like to check to make sure a command line argument is of type bool before I use it in a conditional statement. this: `isinstance(sys.argv[2], bool)` is coming back false. What's the right way to do this?

Comment: whoever downvoted this clearly has not understood what this site is about: you don't vote on the content, you vote on the form. this is actually quite well written as beginner questions go.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All command line arguments are strings. Please refine what you want.

If you want to check for the argument `true`, check if `sys.argv[2]` equals `'true'`.

Answer (score 6):

As nightcracker said, command line arguments are strings.
You can use `sys.argv[2] in ('True', 'False')`.